# Comparing dataframes with different sizes in pandas and create new column based on comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing via pyodbc 2 dataframes: df1 and df2.

They are big and I need to compare them.

**PS: They don't have the same size.**

3 columns size Dataframes:

[image: Sizes and format of dataframes]

**What I want to do:**

If CODUSU columns are equal then df2[Situação] = 'K'

**What I have done, but it's too slow:**

```
for i in range(0,len(df2)):
  for k in range(0,len(df1)):
    if df2.loc[i][0] == df1.loc[k][0]:
        df2[i]["Situação"] = "K"
```

**I also need to:**

If in item in df1[CODUSU] and not in df2[CODUSU] then df2[Situação] = 'Q'

If in item in df2[CODUSU] and not in df1[CODUSU] then df2[Situação] = 'B'

Comment: You can do, `df2.loc[df2['CODUSU'].isin(df1['CODUSU']), 'Situação'] = "K"`

Comment: Seems interesting, I will try soon.

Comment: If you start using loops while dealing with pandas, that's probably the wrong way... As @DOOM wrote, `isin` is the way to go.

Comment: Thansk @HadasArik. That tip will help me a lot for future automatizations!

Answer (score 1):

You should do an outer merge on the dataframes asking for the indicator variable:

```
resul = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', on='A', suffixes=('', '_y'),indicator=True)
```

Do not forget the `DTDOSE` column for rows coming from `df1` only:

```
resul.loc[resul['indicator'] == 'right_only', 'DTDOSE'] = resul.loc[
                                  resul['indicator'] == 'right_only', 'DTDOSE_y']
```

Time to compute the new values for the `Situação` column:

```
resul.loc[resul['indicator'] == 'both', 'Situação'] = 'K'
resul.loc[resul['indicator'] == 'right_only', 'Situação'] = 'Q'
resul.loc[resul['indicator'] == 'left_only', 'Situação'] = 'B'
```

And finally get rid of the auxiliary columns:

```
resul = resul[['CODUSU', 'DTDOSE', 'Situação']
```

Comment: Perfect! This was what I was searching for. Merge was very useful!